# Como puedo renderizar en una app mobil con RN formas o figuras echas en una app web con react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop

Voy a ser especifico y espero poder explicar el problema que tengo y lo que quiero lograr hacer, tengo dos proyectos, una app web con React y una app con React native, el proyecto es de Drag and Drop, en la app web con react uso react-konva, konva para el Drag and Drop. Ahora, lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente, en la app web hay un parte donde renderizo varios elementos que pueden ser dragables y supongamos que alguien cambia las posiciones de cada elemento y las acomoda de una forma que el quiera, ahora que informacion tendria que guardar en mi api (donde manejo la base de datos) para recueperarla desde la app mobil y renderizar en pantalla las figuras como estaban en la app web?

Tengo varias dudas de esto, porque por ejemplo: Las pantallas de la app web cambian su ancho y alto y yo quiero renderizar todo en el ancho y alto de cualquier pantalla mobil (en esta caso tendria que hacer una escala de tamaños? para que se adapte al ancho?)

pondre un codigo sencillo

```
//konva
import { Stage, Layer, Rect, Circle } from 'react-konva';

export default function Draggable() {
    return (
        <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
            <Layer>
                <Rect
                    x={500}
                    y={20}
                    width={100}
                    height={100}
                    fill="red"
                    draggable
                />
                <Circle x={200} y={100} radius={50} fill="green" />
            </Layer>
        </Stage>
    );
}
```

y supongamos que alguien mueve las figuras así (en la app web)
[image: elementos posicionados]

y yo lo que quiero es guardar la información (que supongo que será x,y de las figuras) que me ayuden a renderizar ahora así pero en la app mobil

[image: Ahora asi es como debe de quedar en mobil]

Como logro eso?, espero alguien puede ayudarme, sino se logra explicar el problema díganme en un comentario y edito la publicación